# Production Elixir Not Finding Existing Atoms

Tags: erlang, elixir, ecto

I'm using a library that parses input into maps using already-existing keys (Poison). For whatever reason, in production, it thinks the keys don't exist, and I can't figure out why. I do have a few pieces of information that I'm hoping someone who isn't a rookie is willing to help me figure out what's going on:

1:

If I do an IEX session (iex -S mix), I can run :erlang.binary_to_existing_atom("first_name", :"utf8") without trouble.  But in production, instead I get

```
** (ArgumentError) argument error
  :erlang.binary_to_existing_atom("first_name", :utf8)
```

2:

I can run `:first_name` immediately before `:erlang.binary_to_existing_atom` on production, and it works fine, since by then, the atom has been created. **BUT**, I can't run `:first_name` followed by the library's method: `Poison.Parser.parse!(~s(#{body}), keys: :atoms!)` as it throws the error, which I find to be strange.

3:

I'm using Heroku, not sure if that matters. The atoms are defined within an Ecto model, also not sure if that matters. Any help would be greatly appreciated - thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Erlang compiler optimizes away known pure function calls and replaces them with the call result. This omits the original atom from the module, thus making it non-existent. The bug is here https://bugs.erlang.org/browse/ERL-453 and I might be fixing it.

Answer (score 0):

You'll note that the Erlang documentation says:

> binary_to_existing_atom(Binary, Encoding) -> atom()
>
> Types:
>
> Binary = binary() Encoding = latin1 | unicode | utf8 Works like
>   binary_to_atom/2, but the atom must already exist.
>
> Failure: badarg if the atom does not already exist.

If I were you I'd try to figure out why the `:first_name` atom isn't there before the call is run.

Comment: This is what I'm asking. Why isn't the atom there, if I thought I defined it? What can I do to figure this out?

Comment: Well given that you've only mentioned your call to Poison.Parser, it's hard to guess what's going on. You mention getting the atoms from an Ecto model--maybe you can share a bit more detail about your model?

Comment: One thing I'd check--insure that "body" is what you think it is.  Do an IO.inspect of it or something like that to insure it contains :first_name.

Comment: By the way, I'd also double check that syntax on that function call: "keys: :atoms!"  That exclamation point doesn't look right.